# Prove that these orderings are isomorphic

Tags: order-theory

I want to prove that:
 1) $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{N}$
 2) $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Q}$ (lexicographical order in $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Q}$)
are isomorphic or not.

I know the definition of isomorphic orderings but I don't know how to solve these kind of tasks. Can you give me a hint how to do it correct?

Comment: 1 are not order isomophic.  Find a feature in one that's not in the other.  For example Z has no bottom element, N does.

Comment: @WilliamElliot, thank you, I succeed in solution of the first item and, yes, I have used this information in my solution. But I don't know how to prove the second item(I think it is true)

Comment: What order does N×Q have?

Comment: This is a set of pairs $(x, y)$, where $x\in\mathbb{N}$ and $y\in\mathbb{Q}$, we use lexicographical order, so, there is no bootom element if you mean it

Comment: There is a famous characterization of orderings isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$: countable, no top element, no bottom element, between any two elements there is another. If this result is available, then you can easily see that $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb N\times\mathbb Q$ are isomorphic.

Comment: but is this fact enough to say that they are isomorphic? They have the same cardinality and they are dense, but is this enough?